# Firebase Cloud Functions - Unable to Handle POST Requests

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm encountering an issue with my Firebase Cloud Function that handles POST requests. The goal is to send an email using Nodemailer when a POST request is made to the designated endpoint. However, I'm consistently getting a "Cannot POST /" error, and I'm struggling to identify the root cause.

React component:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://us-central1-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/sendEmail", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      credentials: 'include',
    });

    // Handling the response
```

Cloud function:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://xxx.web.app',
  methods: 'POST',
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'],
  credentials: true
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Rest of code

app.post('/send-email', (req, res) => {
  // Handling email sending logic

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error sending email:', error);
      res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      return res.status(500).json({ error: error.toString() });
    }
    console.log('Email sent:', info);
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.json({ message: 'Email sent successfully!' });
  });
});

export const sendEmail = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I consistently receive the following error when making a POST request to the Cloud Function URL:

```
XHRPOST
https://us-central1-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/sendEmail
[HTTP/3 404 Not Found 124ms]

Response { type: "cors", url: "https://us-central1-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/sendEmail", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers(3), body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
```

I've already checked the CORS configuration, ensured that the Cloud Function is deployed correctly, and verified the URL used in the fetch request. Despite this, the issue persists.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem. Thank you!